# Automatically download and merge webmap tiles into one big image?

Tags: tiles, tilemill, merge, image, web-mapping

Is there an easy way to download a bunch of web map tiles (in /z/x/y.png format) and stitch them together into a single large image? I could probably script this using ImageMagick, but would prefer not to invent another wheel.

(The tiles in question are made by me in TileMill. I'm having serious problems with TileMill's export feature, and thought this might be a workaround.)

Mac or Linux only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, in the end this script did the job:

```
X1=456
Y1=307
X2=469
Y2=316
Z=9
for x in `seq $X1 $X2`; do
for y in `seq $Y1 $Y2`; do
echo "Getting ${x},${y}"
curl -s http://localhost:20008/tile/SteveCountryVic/${Z}/${x}/${y}.png -o ${Z}_${y}_${x}.png &
done
wait
done
montage -mode concatenate -tile "$((X2-X1+1))x" "${Z}_*.png" out_z${Z}_${X1}_${Y1}-${X2}_${Y2}.png
```

The only hassle is working out the values of X1,X2,Y1,Y2. Install imagemagick first:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: +1 A very simple and elegant solution.  On OSX it's: brew install imagemagick

Comment: Thanks, used this as the base for my script which pulls images from a National Parks Service map to generate a high res image.
https://gist.github.com/adamnoffie/98ea29fe41a5384a8738a6410c94e7d9

Comment: I ran your script, but my image looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/kIqqW

Comment: @revo Obviously your Y values are inverted. Just swap your Y2 and Y1.

Comment: tried that, but the result is the same. https://www.mepar.hu/tms/blokk/20170407/${Z}/${x}/${y}.png

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully used taho.exe for such things. You can learn more about it from here:

http://www.dimitri-junker.de/eng/html/openstreetmap.html

You can change the source URL manually to fit your needs; even local addresses with file:///  will do.

You can switch the language to English under `Bearbeiten -> Optionen`. An English help manual is included in the Docu folder.

The programme DYJtracks from the same author and the same download page is a bit more comfortable to get a single map, and works even without a gpx file. But I don't know if you can get it running under Linux using wine.

Comment: I don't know german, so could someone who knows, tell us how we are supposed to use the application? The labels in the UI of the APP are in German, so it will be difficult to use for many people.

Comment: Should have specified: Mac or Linux only.

Comment: If you don't have Windows, you might go back to the original taho.pl using perl.

Comment: This? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Taho Looks ancient (2007), the links to the source code are broken.

Comment: oic: http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/utils/downloading/taho/taho.pl

Comment: Yes, it is ancient, but the tile naming has not changed since then. You might need to use a local apache server to access your tiles via localhost.

Comment: Hmm, well after fiddling around, I got taho up and running, and it did what it did. Which isn't very useful - it downloads tiles and spits out a bunch of configuration files, all of which seem to relate to different GPS software for Windows Mobile devices. How could it be used to stitch together a single image?

Comment: Hmm, combining the (weird) output of taho with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853334/glueing-tile-images-together-using-imagemagicks-montage-command (ImageMagick's 'montage') command worked. Taho is overkill though.

Comment: You have to use the -size and -neighbormaps parameter to stitch the tiles together.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option: https://github.com/ericfischer/tile-stitch

It's a simple command line tool where you specify the desired zoom level along with a bounding box or a center point w/ desired output dimensions in pixels.

The install instructions assume linux, but it compiled easily for me on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [GDAL TMS minidriver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html) and [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html). There several examples explaining how to specifically configure the minidriver depending by how the tile service is made. Furthermore, [here](http://blog.spaziogis.it/2013/01/28/o-che-bel-tassello-marcondirondirondello/)'s a post (in Italian, sorry!) written by [@aborruso](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/466/aborruso) which also answers to your question. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did. No coding required.

I set the region using BigMap 2.
http://bigmap.osmz.ru

Then I used Awesome Screenshot extension and set 'Capture Entire Page'
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce

It might take awhile to capture the screen. It depends on how big your map is.

Finally, I save it to local file.

Comment: You can avoid using browser extensions if you download python or perl code (with the "Python" or "Perl" link) for selected tiles. If you selected less that 100 tiles, you can press "Queue" and receive a stitched image in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't always work, but if you just have the tile images and no other information, you can feed them into [Image Composite Editor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/product/computational-photography-applications/image-composite-editor/) and it will align and combine them (usually).

Answer (score 0):

If you like Python solutions this tiny script may help:
https://github.com/dmserebr/OsmTileMerger

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/222170)

Answer (score -1):

Please check out following links might be helpful for you.

http://ruessel.in-chemnitz.de/osm/qbigmap/

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bigmap

https://github.com/migurski/modestmaps-py

Comment: Thanks. qbigmap: not enough doco for me to be able to build it or try out the binary. (Which "linux" does it target anyway? Is it GUI? Who knows?) Bigmap: can't use the online version, may play with code. modestmaps: not sure how I would use this to solve my problem.